# How to follow a updating local file while using flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, pyflink

As mentioned in the document:

> For example a data pipeline might monitor a file system directory for new files and write their data into an event log. Another application might materialize an event stream to a database or incrementally build and refine a search index.

[image]

So, how can I follow a local file system file updating while using Flink?

[Here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/zh/docs/connectors/table/filesystem/), the document also mentioned  that:

> File system sources for streaming is still under development. In the future, the community will add support for common streaming use cases, i.e., partition and directory monitoring.

Does this mean I could use the API to do some special streaming? If you know how to use streaming file system source, please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: The new FLIP-27 filesystem connector has `monitorContinuously` built into it. I don't know whether this is exposed in PyFlink yet, though.

Comment: @IngoBürk  Thanks!  I searched the code and find there is a `monitor_continuously` in `FileSourceBuilder` under flink-py directory.

Comment: @IngoBürk I have tried the `monitor_continuously` but I found It only could watch new file and read it once. If I append new content to those files, it would not be digested to the source again. Do you know how to enable the FileSourceBuilder to follow in-progress files?

Comment: I don't think monitoring existing files is supported by the connector. I can think of a few problems this would cause, but I don't know if they are the reason for that. You can try asking on the Flink user mailing list as well.

Comment: @IngoBürk Thanks!